# How a window gets created in this GTK application?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/index.html). I'm currently at the [Building applications](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html) part. There is one thing that baffles me, and that is how application window gets created in the first place. Let me explain.

This is how the program starts:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "exampleapp.h"

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (example_app_new ()), argc, argv);
}
```

This is easy. The application is started using `g_application_run` function. The function takes three arguments: an app, argument count and argument vector. Let's see how this app is created.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include "exampleapp.h"
#include "exampleappwin.h"

struct _ExampleApp
{
  GtkApplication parent;
};

G_DEFINE_TYPE(ExampleApp, example_app, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION);

static void
example_app_init (ExampleApp *app)
{
}

static void
example_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
  ExampleAppWindow *win;

  win = example_app_window_new (EXAMPLE_APP (app));
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}

static void
example_app_open (GApplication  *app,
                  GFile        **files,
                  gint           n_files,
                  const gchar   *hint)
{
  GList *windows;
  ExampleAppWindow *win;
  int i;

  windows = gtk_application_get_windows (GTK_APPLICATION (app));
  if (windows)
    win = EXAMPLE_APP_WINDOW (windows->data);
  else
    win = example_app_window_new (EXAMPLE_APP (app));

  for (i = 0; i < n_files; i++)
    example_app_window_open (win, files[i]);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}

static void
example_app_class_init (ExampleAppClass *class)
{
  G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class)->activate = example_app_activate;
  G_APPLICATION_CLASS (class)->open = example_app_open;
}

ExampleApp *
example_app_new (void)
{
  return g_object_new (EXAMPLE_APP_TYPE,
                       "application-id", "org.gtk.exampleapp",
                       "flags", G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN,
                       NULL);
}
```

The line `G_DEFINE_TYPE(ExampleApp, example_app, GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION);`  aliases `ExampleApp` to `GtkApplication` (but in a smart way, such that types, variables, etc. associated with `GtkApplication` are now associated with `ExampleApp`).

Let's now take a look at `ExampleApp *example_app_new(void)` function. This function actually returns `GtkApplication *`, since we associated `ExampleApp` with `GtkApplication`. Next, this function calls and returns a new object by calling `g_object_new` function. That function takes the following arguments:

- `EXAMPLE_APP_TYPE`, which is just `GTK_TYPE_APPLICATION`
- `"application-id"`, which tells that the next argument is the ID of an applicaton
- `"org.gtk.exampleapp"`, the ID
- `"flags"`, which tells that the next argument is a flag
- `"G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN"`, a flag
- `NULL`, terminator

`g_object_new`, called like this, returns `GtkApplication` with the ID of `"org.gtk.exampleapp"` and with a flag `"G_APPLICATION_HANDLES_OPEN"`. After the program goes back to `example_app_new`, it  exits it and returns a new object of type `ExampleApp *` A.K.A. `GtkApplication *` to `main`. The new app is cast to `GApplication` in `g_application_run` using `G_APPLICATION` macro.

---

You have now seen what I understand. Now you'll see what I don't understand.

The tutorial linked at the top of this question says that this creates an empty window. In earlier parts of the tutorial (like [this one](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html#id-1.2.3.5)) we used `g_signal_connect` to call a function when an app is run. For example,

```
g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
```

calls the function `activate` when the app `app` is run using `g_application_run`. Function `activate` will in turn usually create a window and populate it either by itself or by calling other functions. That is what baffles me: there is no such thing in our *example app* program. How then a window gets created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The catch is in overriding `activate` and `open` functions. It says [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/ch01s04.html):

*To handle these two cases, we override the activate() vfunc, which gets called when the application is launched without commandline arguments, and the open() vfunc, which gets called when the application is launched with commandline arguments.*

Therefore, the function

```
static void
example_app_activate (GApplication *app)
{
  ExampleAppWindow *win;

  win = example_app_window_new (EXAMPLE_APP (app));
  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}
```

is called when the application is run without arguments.

```
static void
example_app_open (GApplication  *app,
                  GFile        **files,
                  gint           n_files,
                  const gchar   *hint)
{
  GList *windows;
  ExampleAppWindow *win;
  int i;

  windows = gtk_application_get_windows (GTK_APPLICATION (app));
  if (windows)
    win = EXAMPLE_APP_WINDOW (windows->data);
  else
    win = example_app_window_new (EXAMPLE_APP (app));

  for (i = 0; i < n_files; i++)
    example_app_window_open (win, files[i]);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (win));
}
```

is called when there are given arguments.

Comment: Mainly correct, except for the last paragraph. Pointers are always used, and the arguments to the override and open methods are independent to the arguments to run.

Comment: @ptomato So, the difference between taking `GtkApplication *` and `GApplication *` as a parameter here is just a programmer's preference?

Comment: They point at the same address, but GApplication APIs take a GApplication pointer, while GtkApplication APIs take a GtkApplication pointer. All GtkApplication instances are also GApplication instances, but the reverse is not true.